7 cm length vinyl around the hallway wall
I started putting vinyl flooring from room and then continued to hallway.  I noticed it requires two cut pieces around hallway. One side needs 7cm width. What do I do?is it ok if I put 7cm width flooring cut long the wall? Could you please advise.Here are pictures:
https://ibb.co/g9qSqdw
https://ibb.co/GRtWxWp
https://ibb.co/FwqwkbQ
https://ibb.co/fkS7Rss

You can continue out into the hallway. A transition is not needed. It just takes some diligent work.
First, under cut the door trim so the flooring slides under it. ( pink marks) An oscillating tool and a scrap piece of flooring under the saw blade makes the right cuts.
Have a seam near the middle of the doorway, (blue mark). As long as this seam is at least 8 inches from an adjacent seam it is ok. Seaming at the doorway and having two pieces to cut is easier than trying to properly cut and fit one long piece.
When the doorway is covered, continue down the hallway. If you only need a 7cm (2.75") wide piece it is ok. If there is room to have it fit under the drywall you can tuck it there. You also aren't under pressure to make such a perfect cut. You do need to leave a bit of a gap to the base of the wall as you did with the other pieces already laid, but it isn't as critical because the thinner piece will expand or contract less. This type of flooring is very stable anyway and not likely to be a problem. The baseboards ( skirting boards) and adjacent piece will hold the thin strips it down. I have used a few dabs of latex caulk to keep a strip in place until baseboards were installed.
Continue out from the wall and down the hall. I have installed LVP flooring this way in many homes. I have never had an issue. The same method can be used in most any situation transfering to another room.  Good Luck


Making very narrow cuts is not a great idea. They will be hard to keep in place. Instead, you should probably use transitions at the doorways so that you can split the cuts across the hallway. Or, if you don't mind redoing your work to fix your planning mistake, pull up the flooring you have laid so far and split the difference across the rooms and hallway. That is usually much harder to do though, so transitions are the common solution.

Apart from not having a nice look, I wonder if it would create issue if I put a 7cm wide cut along one side? Is it going to come off?

For example can I glue that 7 cm to make it secure? It is going to be under baseboard.

You asked for advice, so I gave advice.
